# Custom Help Text translation on Standard Field Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, translation, translation-workbench, helptext

I have a custom help text on a standard field. I am able to translate the custom help text using translation workbench, however I am unable to retrieve the corresponding metadata from either a sandbox or scratch org.

For context, translation workbench is enabled and the language is active for translations.

Is this a limitation of metadata API?
Is the only way forward to add the standard field help text translation manually in each environment?

I included the following in my package.xml : 
`

```
<types>
<members>Lead.Phone</members>
<name>CustomField</name>
</types>

<types>
<members>Lead-fr</members>
<name>CustomFieldTranslation</name>
</types>

<types>
<members>Lead</members>
<name>CustomObject</name>
</types>

<types>
<members>Lead-fr</members>
<name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
</types>

<types>
<members>fr</members>
<name>translation</name>
</types>`
```

I am also retrieving all standard value set translations and global value set translations

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [it doesn't look like helptext is exposed through the Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_translations.htm).

You can, however, [export](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workbench_export.htm&type=5) all of the values in your translation workbench into an XLIFF or STF file and [import](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workbench_import.htm&type=5) them into another org. Inconvenient, but certainly better than manually adding them.

Go to Setup, under Translation Workbench select "Export". From here, export *Bilingual*. This creates a collection of files that includes both the source and translation for each language activated in your org which you'll want in order to move the translations. *Source* meanwhile is used for handing off to a translator for a complete translation of the source language and *Untranslated* is to translate translations marked as "Out of Date" or that don't currently have a translation in a target language.

Once exported, in your target org, go to Setup and under Translation Workbench click "Import" to upload translations.

While this should be as seamless as possible, [Salesforce also has an example export file and tips on formatting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325256&type=1&mode=1) should you run into issues.